# MongoClient callback never called

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to mongo db(3.0.6) in multiple ways using nodejs native driver. I have just started writing my application so for the time being all I have there is mongodb and mocha.

Whatever I try, I cannot get to callback/Promise execution. I know it can happen when the connection cannot be established, but I don't get any exception either:

Here are some of the options I've tried:

```
    it('init with Promise', function () {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        test = require('assert');
    console.log("1\n");
    //, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } }
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/session').then(function (db) {
        // This line is never called
        console.log("2\n");
        // Get the collection
        var col = db.collection('insert_many_with_promise');
        col.insertMany([{a: 1}, {a: 2}]).then(function (r) {
            console.log("3\n");
            test.equal(2, r.insertedCount);
            // Finish up test
            db.close();
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.info(error);
    });
})


    it('init db', function () {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var assert = require('assert');
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

    var insertDocument = function (db, callback) {
        db.collection('restaurants').insertOne({
            "address": {
                "street": "2 Avenue",
                "zipcode": "10075",
                "building": "1480",
                "coord": [-73.9557413, 40.7720266]
            },
            "borough": "Manhattan",
            "cuisine": "Italian",
            "grades": [
                {
                    "date": new Date("2014-10-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade": "A",
                    "score": 11
                },
                {
                    "date": new Date("2014-01-16T00:00:00Z"),
                    "grade": "B",
                    "score": 17
                }
            ],
            "name": "Vella",
            "restaurant_id": "41704620"
        }, function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Inserted a document into the restaurants collection.");
            callback();
        });
    };
```

EDIT:
mongodb driver version: "mongodb": "^2.1.4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test has finished before the asynchronous calls have been completed. Add the *done* callback (see testing asynchronous code in [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/)) as parameter:

```
it('init with Promise', function (done) {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        test = require('assert');
    console.log("1\n");
    //, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } }
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/session').then(function (db) {
        // This line is never called
        console.log("2\n");
        // Get the collection
        var col = db.collection('insert_many_with_promise');
        col.insertMany([{a: 1}, {a: 2}]).then(function (r) {
            console.log("3\n");
            test.equal(2, r.insertedCount);
            // Finish up test
            db.close();
            done();
        });
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.info(error);
        done(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Maurits! It worked like a charm. However, there's still some concert that's nagging me. My example was most basic, but what if all my promises are actually inside a different module that I'm writing a unit test for? Passing done callback into my business logic is the last thing I want to do.